# condition in order by clause in cakephp...?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

```
SELECT * FROM `properties` order by (`queue_type` = 'update') desc;
```

how can we run this query using *cakephp* using **pagination**, I need to sort my properties according to the queue type. option in queue type will be update, folio , verification , new and all.

My query is running perfectly in mysql but I need to do it in cakephp but not need to use query function of cakephp.

Please help me quickly.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Where's the pagination code you've tried so far? Add it to your question.

Comment: Read this doc http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#query-setup